# Jquery show() not working in FF

Tags: jquery, firefox, show

I have issues with FF & Jquery .show().

my website shows an embedded map from google in clicking a link.i have got a javascript function that handle this, in safari it works great.FF won't show the map.

this is the js. function:

```
  function mostraPagina(nome){



  if (nome='mappa'){
   $('#mappa').load('contenuti/mappe/mappa_thiene.html');
   $('#dark_background').show(600);
   $('#mappa').show(600);
  }

 }
```

the embedded code from google maps is:

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Via+Murialdo,+4,+Thiene+italy&amp;sll=45.710686,11.475665&amp;sspn=0.002439,0.005676&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Via+Murialdo,+4,+36016+Thiene+Vicenza,+Veneto,+Italy&amp;ll=45.710222,11.475618&amp;spn=0.001219,0.002838&amp;t=h&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

One possible problem:

```
if (nome='mappa'){
```

You're assigning the value of `nome` to `'mappa'` which evaluates to true always (because of the way non-empty strings typecast to true). Your code should probably be

```
if (nome=='mappa'){
```

Answer (score 1):

are you sure this

```
if (nome='mappa'){
```

is what you want?
that would just be like if(true)

should be:

```
if (nome == 'mappa'){
```

which does the comparison you are looking for I guess

but ACTUALLY it should be:

```
if (nome === 'mappa'){
```

which not only comparse the value, but also the type.
Well why not do a regexp test?

```
if (/^mappa$/.test(nome)){
```

:)